# Target must be not null (Load an ImageView with Picasso on Dialog)

Tags: android, dialog, imageview, picasso

i have a problem which the log cat said `target must be no null`
i want to show an image in a Dialog by `onclick` button with Picasso Loader. 
this my code

```
viewsim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(DetailBookingAdmin.this, ""+pathSIM, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DetailBookingAdmin.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.view_sim);
            dialog.setTitle("SIM");
            final ImageView imgsim = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img_sim);
           Picasso.with(v.getContext()).load(pathSIM).into(imgsim);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Log cat said in line `Picasso.with(v.getContext()).load(pathSIM).into(imgsim);` **target must be not null**. Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: check the `R.id.img_sim` is not found.that's why `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use layout inflater.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View newView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_sim, null);

dialog.setContentView(newView);
final ImageView imgsim = (ImageView)newView.findViewById(R.id.img_sim);
...
```

Comment: Thanksss sirr, i appreciate that ^^